# How to disable Quick Actions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've googled extensively for this answer and it looks like being impossible. I've found a lot of people complaining and asking MS to make them optional since VS 2015, with no result. Like them, I think it's impossible to concentrate on your code with lightbulbs and screwdrivers flashing every time you move to another line. But I have a short story to tell.
I have been using VS 2015 for years, both at home and at work, and I have never seen those Quick Actions in my VS installations!
I remember to have tried VS 2017, and given up precisely because of those Quick Actions, which were absolutely new for me. Now I've taken a look at VS 2019, and they are still playing around.
Well, it seems I've found out what's different in my installations. When I right-click my C# code and click on Quick Actions I get this message:
[image]
.
The two computers have a quite different hardware, and in both I have made absolutely standard installations. I have never missed the Quick Actions, but although I have developed some quite complex applications, they were only for my own use. I've never published anything or tried to run them on other computers.
I really think I would like to also break Microsoft CodeAnalysis in VS 2019, so I could use the new features of C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable CodeAnalysis for a project in the project properties> tab Code Analysis. For more details check this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019.

[image]

As for the intelliSense, you can disable it by going to the tools menu > textEditor > C# > IntelliSense and uncheck the checkboxes. 
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I've created a new WindowsForms project in VS 2019 and unchecked both checkboxes in Project properties>Code analysis, and closed and reopened the project. But lightbulbs and screwdrivers keep poping up beside the line numbers.

Comment: The lightbulbs can be disabled, it is the second part of my response. The screwdriver cannot be disabled.

Comment: Now I have unchecked every option in C#>Intellisense, exited and restarted VS, and the lightbulbs are still there.

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me. There is this extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MussiKara.HideSuggestionAndOutliningMargins that may suits you.

Comment: Yes, I had seen this extension. It hides the editor margin, so you also loose the code outlining. Moreover, the lightbulbs appear not only in the margin, but sometimes at the mouse cursor position.